# click on a button using Html Agility node ?c#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, html-agility-pack, awesomium

Convert node to html element or click on button that is in node form of html agility here in my html of node

```
nodes[i].ChildNodes[7].NextSibling.NextSibling.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[47].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0]
```

here is html actual

```
  <i class="a-icon a-icon-1click"></i>
  <input name="submit.one-click-dropdown-purchase" class="a-button-input" type="submit" value="Buy with 1-Click" aria-labelledby="a-autoid-3-announce"><span class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true" id="a-autoid-3-announce">
                            Buy with 1-Click
                        </span>
```

get from debugging where i stand now no option for inner-child , nextsibbling So,

x path of input button is

```
       //*[@id="a-autoid-1"]/span/input
  then //*[@id="a-autoid-3"]/span/input
```

as there is no id of button only **node** and then x path available why this is not clicking i am trying this code

[Awesomium Getting and clicking a Tags attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758565/awesomium-getting-and-clicking-a-tags-attribute)

what the problem there ? can any body tell me how to click on this input button in awsomium browser ?

Comment: ANYBODY WITH LITTLE HELP?

Comment: Have a look at this question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659356/how-to-invoke-click-using-html-agility-pack) TL;DR you can't because HAP simply parses a web page. You need a different tool usch as Selenium.